# If html page doesn't have the special links, then give an alert with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web

A javascript function must search the special links (copyright urls) in a web page (html body).

If it doesn't find the special urls, then must give an alert.

**Example of JavaScript file:**

```
if () {

//If function find the copyright links, then null - don't make anything
}
else
//If function doesn't find copyright links, then give an alert
alert("Please protect original copyright links.")
```

**Example of html page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http:// ... file.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Start Copyrigt Area -->
  <div id="footer">
    <a href="http://example1.com">example1.com</a>
    <a href="http://example2.com">example2.com</a>
  </div>
  <!-- End Copyrigt Area -->

</body>
</html>
```

> **WHY?**
>
> I made some themes for special blog community site.  Sometimes, our
>   theme users remove or change our copyright links in the footer area.
>
> The blog community site doesn't support any dynamic content like php,
>   we can use only html and some special content tags in a one page.
>
> On the other side, this site doesn't allow JS hosting, etc. So, JS
>   files provided by third party hosting providers.
>
> I don't want encrypt the code.  So I think we check the links with a
>   JavaScript function.  If our links removed or changed, then users must
>   get an alert.
>
> Maybe, some theme users find these javascript function and removes
>   them and re-host the codes. But I think most of them will can not
>   anything.

Comment: Trawling the DOM won't stop them from editing the CSS to `display:none;`

Comment: Hit some URL silently instead so you can contact those folks.  It's trivial for them to remove the alert, but many will probably not be watching network requests.

Comment: `if (document.getElementById('footer') === null) { alert('this "protection" is futile'); }`

Comment: If they can remove the footer they can also remove your Javascript code.

Comment: This is no different than people who want to disable source viewing, right clicking, etc. There will always be a way around it. Don't waste your time.

Comment: @PeeHaa read my note "WHY?"

Comment: @DC_ read my note "WHY?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you write your html. Assuming the footer element is always there:

```
if (document.getElementById('footer').childNodes.length == 0) {

//If function find the copyright links, then null - don't make anything
}
else
//If function doesn't find copyright links, then give an alert
alert("Please protect original copyright links.")
```

but remember, this just counts what you put in there.

If your footer is absent if you did not put copyrights in, then see peehaa's comment.

Should be good to note, however, that it looks like you're just referencing links in the copyright area. Like saying - I understand this measure does nothing in the way of security, but in case you care, here are links to the rights owners. If this is true, then goody. Here you go. If you actually want security in place to copyright the content on a page, this will not protect anything.

Comment: did the update clear anything up? I'm not sure how to make it any clearer

Comment: It's not my favorite solution but thanks a lot for your helps.

Comment: Nor mine, but it is kind of hard to tell the goal of this function at a glance.