# JavaScript Function will check the special links on a web page, If it doesn't find them, then it will give an alert

Tags: javascript, html, web

A javascript function must search the special links (copyright urls) in a html web page.
If it doesn't find the special urls, then must give an alert. "Div ID check" and "Div length check" are good ways, but is it possible to directly control the links (urls)?

I am already aware that this does not protect the links.

**Example of JavaScript file:**

```
if () {
//If function find the copyright links, then null - don't make anything:

}
else {
//If function doesn't find copyright links, then give an alert:
alert("Please protect original copyright links.");
}
```

**Example of html page:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http:// ... file.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Start Copyrigt Area -->
  <div id="footer">
    <a href="http://example1.com">example1.com</a>
    <a href="http://example2.com">example2.com</a>
  </div>
  <!-- End Copyrigt Area -->

</body>
</html>
```

A far as why I am doing this is concerned, here are my reasons:

I made some themes for special blog community site.  Sometimes, our theme users remove or change our copyright links in the footer area. The blog community site doesn't support any dynamic content like php, we can use only html and some special content tags in a one page.
On the other side, this site doesn't allow JS hosting, etc. So, JS files provided by third party hosting providers.

I don't want encrypt the code.  So I think we check the links with a JavaScript function.  If our links removed or changed, then users must get an alert.

Maybe, some theme users find these javascript function and removes them and re-host the codes. But I think most of them will can not anything.

Comment: No problem. You might want to have a look at the [help page on markdown](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help). For example, you don't need `<br/>` tags to start a new line.

Comment: What is it that you want to check, the link's URL or the text or both?

Comment: @LEOPiC There are no similar links like special copyright links. So all ways is good.

Comment: What's with this version of the same question which you've asked four times now? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593777/if-html-page-doesnt-have-the-special-links-then-give-an-alert-with-javascript

Comment: @Andreas, Unfortunately I can't find any solution like on this post. Sorry.

Comment: I founded the best solution @Andreas. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, I think you should check both the link and it's text. Suppose you're using JQuery:

```
​$().ready(function(){
    var copyrightLinks = $("a[href='your copyright url']");
    //check link and inner text
    if(copyrightLinks .length > 0 && copyrightLinks.text().indexOf("your copyright text")>=0){
        console.debug("has copy right");
    }else{
        alert("Please protect original copyright links.");
    }
});​
```

Comment: I think your answer was one of the the best ways. But my JavaScript knowledge isn't good. Can you make a full example. When I remove the links, page gives an alert on example.

Comment: Thanks for your great helps Chris. I'm grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var allLinks = document.links;
for (var i=0; i<allLinks.length; i++) {
  if(allLinks[i].text=="&copy;"){
     //do something
  }
  else {
    //If function doesn't find copyright links, then give an alert:
    alert("Please protect original copyright links.");
  }
}
```

Comment: That would trigger as soon as there's any non-(c) link on the page, wouldn't it? (Or else I need more coffee, which is entirely possible.)

Comment: @Murali, My JavaScript knowledge isn't good. Can you make a full example. When I remove the links, page gives an alert on example.

Comment: Thanks for your great helps Murali.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all your document links by **getElementsByTagName**:

```
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var noLinks = true;
for (var i=0, len=a.length; i<len; ++i) {
    var href = a[i].getAttribute('href');       
    if (href == "copylink1" || href == "copylink2") {
        noLinks = false;
        break;
    }
}

if (noLinks) {    
    alert('...')
}
```

Comment: My JavaScript knowledge isn't good. Can you make a full example. When I remove the links, page gives an alert on example.

Comment: Thanks for your great helps. According to me everything seems great. I edited copylink1 as http://example1.com and copylink2 as http://example2.com but I get an alert. This may be caused by?

Comment: Thanks for your great helps prodigy.